# Jmeter : Help me out in Jmeter Server performance monitoring plugin

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have tried the methods to monitor the server performance monitoring as mentioned in the [Jmeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) site.
There is no firewall between the client and server system.

Can anyone clearly specify the steps to be performed in server performance monitoring?

Comment: You need to be a *lot* more specific. What type of server you are trying to monitor is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using perfmon? If yes, then it is really pretty simple and well documented on the plugin site.

1. Put the monitoring agent on the server machine and run it ( run startAgent.bat )
2. Make sure that there is a connection on the port 4444 from the load machine to the server machine
3. Add the perfmon listener to your test plan and add your server to the listener ( press the Add Row button and change localhost to your server name or ip )
4. Add thread group and set to forever, which in actual fact will continue collecting metrics from your agent.